# Thunar: set different default applications for *.rkt files and *.txt files

Tags: default-programs, file-format, mime-type

1. The problem: whenever I set a default program for opening *.rkt files, it also becomes the default program for opening *.txt files. Whenever I set a default program for opening *.txt files, it also becomes the default program for opening *.rkt files.
2. What I've tried: adding `text/x-racket                   rkt` to `/etc/mime.types`. No effect.
3. What else I've tried: creating an `/usr/share/mime/text/x-racket.xml` file with the following contents:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-type xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info" type="text/x-racket">
  <glob pattern="*.rkt"/>
</mime-type>`

Then updating the mime database with `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`.

No effect, the problem persists.

4. Now I have no idea what to do and would appreciate any help.

Comment: How are your `*.rkt` files different from `*.txt` files, other than the name? `man file`, then `file --mime --keep-going *.rkt` will give you more info.

Comment: They are not. It seems like my idea about what `file` does was wrong. Edited the question so it won't distract anyone. Still, the problem persists.